# Jmeter - what is the regular expression to extract a boolean value from a response

Tags: regex, boolean, jmeter

What regex should I enter in the Regular Expression Extractor component - field: Regular Expression for a boolean field in the response called "enabled". I tried to reference it as a string - "enabled" : "(.+?)" - but it is not working. Please help.

Comment: Try `"enabled"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)"`

Comment: can you please share the partial response from which we need to retrieve 4-5 lines before and after "enabled"?

Comment: Nope, still not working - I tried "enabled"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)" and "enabled":"\s*:\s*"([^"]+)". Should I change the Template field as well, currently it is with value $1$

Comment: can you please share the screenshot of RegExExtractor and the JSON response?

Comment: Response: {
  "userid" : 33331,
  "userName" : "123",
  "firstName" : "first name",
  "lastName" : "last name",

  "email" : [ {
    "id" : 123,
    "email" : "30097@gmam"
  } ],
  "prNonExpired" : true,
  "prNonLocked" : true,
  "crNonExpired" : true,
  "enabled" : true,
  "prDisabled" : false
}

Comment: Screenshot: http://s1255.photobucket.com/user/ilennaa2017/library/?view=recent&page=1

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to surround your regular expression with quotation marks as `true` is not surrounded with them
2. You need to either add comma to the end of the regular expression like:

   ```
   "enabled": (.+?),
   ```

   or even better change it to match the "word" like:

   ```
   "enabled": (\w+)
   ```

   [image: Regular Expression]
3. In general it is much easier to use [JSON Path PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Path_PostProcessor) or [JSON Path Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0) plugin in order to deal with JSON data, the relevant JSON Path query will be as simple as:

   ```
   $.enabled
   ```

   [image: JSON PAth]